# NestJS createTestingModule and getHttpServer() error 503

Tags: unit-testing, nestjs, e2e-testing

I'm using NestJS 7.6.0 and I'm experiencing a problem with E2E testing.

I have a very simple module that exposes a /health route in its controller. I'd like to test this route using the E2E testing feature of nestJs documented here:

https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/testing#end-to-end-testing

I'm currently using the quite same code:

```js
describe('AppController (e2e)', () => {

    let app: INestApplication;
    beforeAll(async () => {
        const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({     
            imports: [AppModule]
        }).compile();

        app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
        await app.init();
    }); 

    it('/health (GET)', async() => {
        return await request(app.getHttpServer())
            .get('/health')
            .expect(200)
    });
});
```

If I run this test with `npm run test` I have this error:

```
npm run test

> dv-ewok-api@0.0.1 test ....
> jest

[Nest] 54638   - 28/06/2021, 14:53:30   [ExceptionHandler] Health Check has failed! {"ready":{"status":"down","message":"connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000"}}
 FAIL  src/health/health.controller.spec.ts
  ● AppController (e2e) › /health (GET)

    expected 200 "OK", got 503 "Service Unavailable"

  32 |         return await request(app.getHttpServer())
  33 |             .get('/health')
> 34 |             .expect(200)
     |              ^
  35 |
  36 |     });
  37 | });
```

It seems that the httpServer is not running.

To make it work I have to modify the code like this:

```js
...
beforeAll(async () => {
        const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({     
            imports: [AppModule]
        }).compile();

        app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
        await app.init();
        await app.listen(3000); // <===== ADD THIS LINE
    }); 
...
```

I just added a `app.listen(3000)` and the test passed. I don't know if this is an oversight in the documentation or if I did it wrong.

Thank you for your help.

### Edit for adding some more details

For the HealthCheck part, I'am using the NestJS Terminus integration [described here](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/terminus).

So, my app.module looks like this :

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TerminusModule } from '@nestjs/terminus';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { HealthController } from './health/health.controller';

@Module({
  imports: [TerminusModule],
  controllers: [AppController, HealthController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

As you can see, I import the TerminusModule and I declare my 2 controllers: AppController and HealthController.

In **AppController** I have just a /ping route that says "hello world"

```js
import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  @Get('/ping')
  getHello(): string {
    return this.appService.getHello();
  }
}
```

And in **HealthController** I have just the /health route that calls the /ping on localhost.

```js
import { Controller, Get } from "@nestjs/common";
import { HealthCheck, HealthCheckService, HttpHealthIndicator } from "@nestjs/terminus";

@Controller('health')
export class HealthController {
  constructor(
    private health: HealthCheckService,
    private http: HttpHealthIndicator,
  ) {}

  @Get()
  @HealthCheck()
  check() {
    return this.health.check([
      () => this.http.pingCheck('ping', 'http://localhost:3000/ping'),
    ]);
  }
}
```

And if you run tests with `npm run test`, it shows the 503 error linked above. To make it work, I need to add `await app.listen(3000);` in the beforeAll() method right after the init() (cf. above).

I think my problem comes from "terminus" because if I start a new NestJS project which does not use Terminus, e2e testing works fine, without the need to add the .listen().

Do I need to do something special in the createTestingModule() with TerminusModule?

Thank you

Comment: Please share the contents of the Health endpoint. You shouldn't have to add an HTTP listener in order to run this test